# Data type mismatch while transforming data in spark dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, apache-spark-dataset

I created a parquet-structure from a csv file using spark:

```
Dataset<Row> df = park.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferSchema", "true")
            .option("header", "true").load("sample.csv");
df.write().parquet("sample.parquet");
```

I'm reading the parquet-structure and I'm trying to transform the data in a dataset:

```
Dataset<org.apache.spark.sql.Row> df = spark.read().parquet("sample.parquet");
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmpview");
Dataset<Row> namesDF = spark.sql("SELECT *, md5(station_id) as hashkey FROM tmpview");
```

Unfortunately I get a data type mismatch error. Do I have to explicitly assign data types?

> 17/04/12 09:21:52 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: SELECT *,
>   md5(station_id) as hashkey FROM tmpview Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve
>   'md5(tmpview.`station_id`)' due to data type mismatch: **argument 1
>   requires binary type, however, 'tmpview.`station_id`' is of int type.;**
>   line 1 pos 10; 'Project [station_id#0, bikes_available#1,
>   docks_available#2, time#3, md5(station_id#0) AS hashkey#16]
>   +- SubqueryAlias tmpview, `tmpview`    +- Relation[station_id#0,bikes_available#1,docks_available#2,time#3]
>   parquet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as per Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#md5(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)), `md5` function works only on `binary` (text/string) columns so you need to cast `station_id` into `string` before applying `md5`. In Spark SQL, you can chain both `md5` and `cast` together, e.g.:

```
Dataset<Row> namesDF = spark.sql("SELECT *, md5(cast(station_id as string)) as hashkey FROM tmpview");
```

Or you can create a new column in dataframe and apply `md5` on it, e.g.:

```
val newDf = df.withColumn("station_id_str", df.col("station_id").cast(StringType))
newDf.createOrReplaceTempView("tmpview");
Dataset<Row> namesDF = spark.sql("SELECT *, md5(station_id_str) as hashkey FROM tmpview");
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are experiencing this error on Databricks (Azure Databricks Notebooks)
which run on 3.x clusters following snippet might work for you.

```
md5(cast(concat_ws('some string' + 'some string') + """)as BINARY))
```